# Add 'Surrounds With' Type Code Snippet To Existing Collection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

We can add a 'Surrounds With' style code snippet to Visual Studio using a tool such as [Snippet Designer](https://github.com/mmanela/SnippetDesigner) or just 'by hand' by writing the appropriate `.snippet` file & importing to visual studio.

Once this snippet is added, however, it is placed into a separate sub-menu that adds an extra (unnecessary) keystroke to ALL "Surround With" type snippets. I'd like to avoid this extra step.

To highlight my point:

With no custom snippets added, if we were to highlight a few lines of code and hit Ctrl+K,Ctrl+S we'd get this drop down:

[image]

From this menu we can then type `if` then `<tab>` to use the 'if' code snippet, for example. All Good.

Now if i add my own 'surrounds with' code snippet using either the snippet designer or just adding by hand, when I select some code and hit Ctrl+K,Ctrl+S again i hit *this* menu instead:

[image]

So now I have to choose between the built in snippet list and my custom ones adding an extra step. Typing `if` then `<tab>` no longer works until I have selected the Visual C# option.

This extra step turns the previous `Ctrl+s,Ctrl+k,if,<tab>` key combo into a much more cumbersome combo: `Ctrl+s,Ctrl+k,<tab>,<downarrow>,<tab>,if,<tab>`

**I'd really like to be able to add my custom 'surrounds with' type snippets to the *existing* menu without the extra sub-menu appearing. Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy it in the folder (using file explorer, not using visual studio):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#
```

Then they will appear under the normal popup menu. It requires administrator rights though.

[image]

For example I added a snippet to insert a stopwatch:

[image]